# Packaging applications for Mesos

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I can use e.g. Marathon + Docker to easily run my long running applications, and applications are packaged as Docker images and retrieved from public/private registry.

However, if I were to create my own framework (such as has been done for Cassandra and Spark) how would I go about to "packaging" my application?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Docker containers, since Docker is supported directly in Mesos. That's actually how Marathon does it.

As an alternative, you can have multiple files and/or archives that have to be fetched prior to task start.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop your own framework you can start from here: [Framework Tutorial](http://codefutures.com/mesos-docker-tutorial-how-to-build-your-own-framework/) and [Mesos Framework Development Guide](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/app-framework-development-guide/).

Usually you use a containerizer to run your application/code inside: The two standard containerizer are [Mesos Containerizer](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/mesos-containerizer/) and [Docker Containerizer](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/docker-containerizer/) (this means you can still use Docker for your own frameworks as alex mentioned).